# Errors during the installation of tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, command-prompt

I am not able update(upgrade) my tensorflow-gpu and am being shown various error. Even after trying to google every single error of them, one or the other conflicted to result in throwing errors in red fonts.
Can you please help me installing (upgrading) tensorflow-gpu error free by having this thread replied with the commands I'm supposed to be passing.
Here's the list of errors I see

````
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Using cached tensorflow_gpu-2.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (356.5 MB)
Collecting scipy==1.4.1; python_version >= "3"
  Using cached scipy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (30.9 MB)
Collecting keras-applications>=1.0.8
  Using cached Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (50 kB)
Collecting google-pasta>=0.1.6
  Using cached google_pasta-0.1.8-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0
  Using cached numpy-1.18.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (12.8 MB)
Processing c:\users\shash\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\2c\b1\94\43d03e130b929aae7ba3f8d15cbd7bc0d1cb5bb38a5c721833\opt_einsum-3.1.0-cp37-none-any.whl
Processing c:\users\shash\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\7c\06\54\bc84598ba1daf8f970247f550b175aaaee85f68b4b0c5ab2c6\termcolor-1.1.0-cp37-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel>=0.26; python_version >= "3"
  Using cached wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting astor>=0.6.0
  Using cached astor-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting wrapt>=1.11.1
  Downloading wrapt-1.12.0.tar.gz (27 kB)
Collecting tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0
  Using cached tensorboard-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.8 MB)
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6
  Using cached grpcio-1.27.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.9 MB)
Collecting keras-preprocessing>=1.1.0
  Using cached Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
Processing c:\users\shash\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\8e\28\49\fad4e7f0b9a1227708cbbee4487ac8558a7334849cb81c813d\absl_py-0.9.0-cp37-none-any.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.8.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.11.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting tensorflow-gpu-estimator<2.2.0,>=2.1.0rc0
  Using cached tensorflow_gpu_estimator-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (464 kB)
Collecting six>=1.12.0
  Using cached six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Processing c:\users\shash\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\5c\2e\7e\a1d4d4fcebe6c381f378ce7743a3ced3699feb89bcfbdadadd\gast-0.2.2-cp37-none-any.whl
Collecting h5py
  Using cached h5py-2.10.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (2.5 MB)
Collecting google-auth<2,>=1.6.3
  Using cached google_auth-1.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Collecting requests<3,>=2.21.0
  Downloading requests-2.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 58 kB 443 kB/s
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8
  Using cached Markdown-3.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88 kB)
Collecting setuptools>=41.0.0
  Using cached setuptools-45.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (584 kB)
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.15
  Using cached Werkzeug-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached cachetools-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4
  Using cached rsa-4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 58 kB 363 kB/s
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0
  Using cached requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6
  Using cached pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting oauthlib>=3.0.0
  Using cached oauthlib-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: wrapt
  Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for wrapt: filename=wrapt-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl size=19565 sha256=8fcffad77f7712e3dcab457e1b9f25ef120f4fd4e925ce3049c8b256f9ec31fa
  Stored in directory: c:\users\shash\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\e5\78\69\f40ab7cae531c8f07003a9d1b4b81ebec14cda95519c57e7dd
Successfully built wrapt
ERROR: Error checking for conflicts.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3021, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2815, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3012, in _parsed_pkg_info
    return self._pkg_info
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2815, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _pkg_info

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 517, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 114, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set, _ = create_package_set_from_installed()
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 53, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2736, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3023, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3032, in _compute_dependencies
    for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3014, in _parsed_pkg_info
    metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1420, in get_metadata
    value = self._get(path)
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1616, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'd:\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pyparsing-2.4.2.dist-info\\METADATA'
Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy, six, h5py, keras-applications, google-pasta, opt-einsum, termcolor, wheel, astor, wrapt, cachetools, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, setuptools, rsa, google-auth, chardet, certifi, idna, urllib3, requests, absl-py, markdown, protobuf, grpcio, werkzeug, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, google-auth-oauthlib, tensorboard, keras-preprocessing, tensorflow-gpu-estimator, gast, tensorflow-gpu
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'd:\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\random\\tests\\data\\mt19937-testset-1.csv'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.```


Also I see an error on trying to import tensorflow within a shell command.
The error is as follows:

```C:\Users\shash>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:32: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.PYQHXLVVQ7VESDPUVUADXEVJOBGHJPAY.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.TXA6YQSD3GCQQC22GEQ54J2UDCXDXHWN.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
  stacklevel=1)
2020-02-29 17:24:19.169004: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-02-29 17:24:19.175109: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
>>> ```

Thanks in advance.
````

Comment: It says Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```sh
pip install --user some_pkg
```

Comment: What some_pkg are you referring to?

Comment: I mean use the library which you want to install.(ex : pip install --user TensorFlow-GPU) and also try to use the version number(TensorFlow-GPU == 2.0.0)